# Filtering users with filter function - React with next.js and typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

i'm developing my fronted app with next.js and typescript, and i'm trying to filter an array in order to show only the users that you are looking for, like a search bar, but, it returns me always undefined.

Let me show you a litle bit of my code.

Firts of all, the function i made **filteredUsers**

```
const [searchBar, setSearchBar] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const [results, setResults] = useState<string>("");

  // Searchbar users

  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    const userId: dataObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Auth"));
    var { data }: multipleUsers = useSWR(
      "http://localhost:5000/api/user/allU/" + userId.user.id
    );
  }

  const filteredUsers = useMemo(() => {
    data !== undefined &&
      data.filter(user => {
        return user.name.toLowerCase().includes(results.toLowerCase());
      });
  }, [results]);

  console.log(filteredUsers);
  console.log(results);
```

Now, the interfaces to understand what type of data i'm expecting

```
// User representation

type user = {
  id?: string;
  name?: string;
  email?: string;
  password?: string;
  friends?: [];
  banner?: string;
  perfil?: string;
};

export interface IuserData {
  data: user;
}

export type multipleUsers = { data: user[] };
```

Now, let me show you what the console.log() is showing for me

[image]

**First value** is the data i'm receving.

**The second one** is the result of my function, which is undefined always

**Third one** is the value of my input

What can i do in order to get the results i'm looking for based on the value of my input ?

Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 1):

Add `data` to the `useMemo` second argument, so `[results]` turn to `[data, results]`.
Otherwise its always use data as its initial value, with is undefined

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's still undefined, i tried to assign data.filter(user => {
        return user.name.toLowerCase().includes(results.toLowerCase());
      }); to a variable and i console log it, and it returns false and true, it seems that it's working fine, but i have to figure out why it keeps givin me undefined

Comment: I cut the useMemo function, and everything it's working great, why with useMemo it would give me undefined? I need to use it

Comment: what if you put the use memo inside the `if` block? so the usememo initiated only when `useSwr is defined

Comment: I think that'll do the trick, thanks for your answers !!